# Google Cloud Run vs. GKE portability

Tags: containers, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

i am looking to deploy a brand new web app we are developing in containers. i am very worried about vendor lock-in. I'd like to be able to easily pick up and move from google to Azure or AWS if i choose. Is there a difference in portability between GKE and GCR?

Thanks,
Al

Comment: why are you very worried about vendor lock-in?

Comment: Are you speaking french? (I should have a recorded french session about this topic)

Answer (score 1):

In general, containers are portable between vendors. However, there are numerous features that containers can benefit from that can create vendor dependencies.

Deploying containers is easy. Mastering the container services such as Cloud Run, Kubernetes, Fargate, ACI, etc. requires an investment in training that often exceeds the cost of the service.

Containers often require Authorization, Storage, Databases, and/or Messaging/Queues. Those items are more likely to create vendor-specific implementations.

You must clearly define what services your containers require or implement before you know if you have vendor lock-in. If you require cross-cloud portability, then you will need to deploy your containers cross-cloud and validate the features, behavior, and performance.

Comment: In general, your development are sticky to the platform to leverage the services and the power of it. Being absolutely agnostic is a myth, and not so productive and performant, and absolutely not valuable for the users. It's better to know which part of your app are sticky, and which parts aren't, and develop wisely with that in mind.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  As stated in my answer it depends. I have production containers that deploy from GitHub on Cloud Run, Azure ACI, and Amezmo without any changes. This includes Laravel and ASP.NET Core applications.  Two examples: https://videolabs.jhanley.com/ and https://codelabs.jhanley.com/

Comment: It's maybe a mistake from me, but this type of service, which only process the data, are more rare than service with a database. And when you use database, it's more performant to use Cloud Provider services than hosted one in a K8S cluster. Of course, nothing is impossible but in term of price/cost/perf it's better.